# Strange phone model - Rmob-i9988_custom detected programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I try to detect phone model and brend in my application on Android and there is something strange returns - Rmob-i9988_custom. Do you know what is it? Maybe it's emulator?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Answer for myself. Yes. It's emulator.